# Using German GPT-2 in Rasa

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, language-model

Does the Rasa Framework also allow the use of the German GPT-2 model (https://huggingface.co/dbmdz/german-gpt2) with the LanguageModelFeaturizer? I had also tried two older Rasa 2. x versions. There it did not work as well. Does anyone know more?
Thanks in advance.
I tried it and get, among other things, the error message (in Rasa 3.x)

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

and

````
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tests\lib\site-packages\rasa\engine\graph.py", line 403, in _load_component
    raise GraphComponentException(
rasa.engine.exceptions.GraphComponentException: Error initializing graph component for node run_LanguageModelFeaturizer1.```
````

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving this question to the forum and also sharing your config.yml.